# jQuery :contains in a variable and for loop

Tags: jquery, variables, contains

i have this:

```
for(y=0; y<numbers_sold.length; y++){
    $("#stickers a:contains('" + numbers_sold[y] + "')").addClass('sold');  
}
```

It doesn't work. If substitute the variable `numbers_sold` by a number it works...
Can you help?

Thanks.

Comment: What is in the variable `numbers_sold[y]`? number, string, or? everything seems ok to me? http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/9raA8/

Answer (score 1):

what is here not working? It works for me. see http://jsfiddle.net/3Du3K/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
    $.each(numbers_sold, function(i, val){
    $("#stickers a:contains('" + val + "')").addClass('sold');
});
```